# Xauthority file inside /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority instead of my home directory

Tags: 20.04, permissions, xorg, login, gdm

I'm currently experiencing the log-in loop bug, and I found out that the .Xauthority file isn't in my home drive at all, but rather inside /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority. None of the websites I used to fix the issue mentioned what I should do if the Xauthority isn't in my home directory. This is a freshly installed operating system.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKNxA.png)

By the way, 1000 is not my username. I have no idea what 1000 is. My home directory doesn't contain the Users directory.

Comment: There may be some confusion. Can you describe the actual problem that you face?  Otherwise, it seems like this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  Not every solution you find online is accurate. It may not pertain to Ubuntu, or the version or flavor of Ubuntu you are using. It's better to describe and provide details about your problem. Especially since you are looking for a "Users" folder under `/home`, because that doesn't exist.  However there will be a folder for your username under `/home`

Comment: I'm experience a problem where after entering my password, I get looped back into the login screen. I searched online and most solutions involve renaming, moving, or changing ownership of a file called Xauthority, which for me is not in the home directory as these solutions suggest.